# Save a JSON String which is generated by Javascript as a file: web2py

Tags: javascript, python, json, python-2.7, web2py

[Log] {"image":"/SAS/default/download/uploads.image.85f2588e34848596.30362d32353033392e746966.tif","filename":"/SAS/default/download/06-25039.tif","start":1437444049436,"width":1080,"height":734,"events":[{"colour":"#0000ff","width":3,"erased":false,"points":[{"x":795,"y":256,"time":1437444050332},{"x":754,"y":260,"time":1437444050338},{"x":642,"y":271,"time":1437444050355},{"x":466,"y":291,"time":1437444050372},{"x":268,"y":318,"time":1437444050389},{"x":148,"y":344,"time":1437444050406},{"x":101,"y":359,"time":1437444050423},{"x":92,"y":369,"time":1437444050441},{"x":104,"y":377,"time":1437444050458},{"x":161,"y":381,"time":1437444050475},{"x":268,"y":381,"time":1437444050492},{"x":405,"y":366,"time":1437444050509},{"x":513,"y":346,"time":1437444050527},{"x":557,"y":328,"time":1437444050544},{"x":554,"y":315,"time":1437444050562},{"x":529,"y":305,"time":1437444050579},{"x":484,"y":301,"time":1437444050596},{"x":435,"y":304,"time":1437444050613},{"x":401,"y":316,"time":1437444050630},{"x":388,"y":329,"time":1437444050648},{"x":389,"y":342,"time":1437444050665},{"x":406,"y":356,"time":1437444050682},{"x":430,"y":367,"time":1437444050699},{"x":449,"y":370,"time":1437444050716},{"x":457,"y":370,"time":1437444050733},{"x":458,"y":370,"time":1437444050751},{"x":457,"y":368,"time":1437444050769}]}],"end":1437444051345,"elapsed":1909} (experiment, line 164)

This is the String which I need to save.I have to perform two tasks:

1. Save the string on the system and display it as a View(as it is)
2. Display a specific argument only. Such as "elapsed" in this string as a View.

How do I do this?
 Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: [Python comes with batteries included](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html). In this case, a json module.

Comment: You have those 2 tasks. Great! now all we need is a question.

Comment: Why do you have to down vote the question if you can't answer it in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what/how you want to display your JSON string, you have some different options. If you want to display the raw JSON string stored in variable strJSON, you can just inject it into the view at the appropriate location with {{ =strJSON }}. web2py has a built-in method BEAUTIFY which makes injected variable outputs look nicer, i.e. you'd call {{ =strJSON }} to take advantage of this.

If you want to only print certain elements &/or manually format it yourself, as in your second question, I'd recommend converting the JSON string back into a Python object. web2py has a module called SimpleJSON which does all the JSON encoding/decoding magic for you. It's located at gluon.contrib.simplejson. To convert a JSON string to an object, you would use the function 'loads'. For converting a Python object into a JSON string, use 'dumps'. So, for example:

{{ import gluon.contrib.simplejson as sjson }}

{{ myObj = sjson.loads(strJSON) }}

{{ strJSON = sjson.dumps(myObj) }}

Now that your JSON string is stored as an object, you can access elements like you normally would in Python based on whether your object is a list, dictionary, etc. So, for example, if we turn the JSON from your screenshot into an object, we can access the image name as so in Python:

imgname = myObj["image"]

Similarily, you can access the first event via:

my_events = myObj["events"][0]

Which is a dictionary of 'colour', 'width', etc.